# Angular 6: MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webpack

I have recently upgraded my project to Angular 6 with Angular CLI and in the browser I get the following error.
I generate the files with Angular CLI and include them with script tag inside my application, but after upgrading receive this error message in Chrome.

Related Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325

Answer (score 0):

In migration to Angular-cli v6, the property **"deployUrl"** was moved from **"apps"** to **"projects.home.architect.build.options"**.

In my experience this property was removed, and not moved to right local.

I've believe if you sets the old property from your old *.angular-cli.json* to the new *angular.json*, this will work.

Obs: In some cases it seems the property **"baseHref"** also works, I didn't tested.